# Empty Pipeline Batch Log file after running

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am using Sitecore 9.0 version 171219 with data exchange framework 2.0 and after following the steps in the below link to use restful provider and starting the pipeline patch nothing happened and the summary file is empty.

http://dataexchange.loveyourdemo.com/
https://github.com/waughn/data-exchange-restful-provider

Any help for how to debug this issue or if there are any other logs that i can check?

Comment: Was the tenant enabled when you ran it?

Comment: yes, Run Pipeline Batch button is enabled but when i clicked it nothing happened and other buttons like "Stop Pipeline Batch " is still disabled, and the summary log file is empty.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, check out this link https://neilkillen.com/2017/12/18/hey-def-2-0-where-have-my-batch-messages-gone/
and do the workaround listed in it, it will fix the batch messages not showing at least ..

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify that needed log levels are set

   [image]
2. If after the running it is still empty it can be known issue. Reed the article mentioned in the comment above. [Hey DEF 2.0 where have my batch messages gone?](https://neilkillen.com/2017/12/18/hey-def-2-0-where-have-my-batch-messages-gone/).
3. If you see some logs but it is not enough, means that provider you use does not cover everything with logs.